# factorial of given number

Tags: java, do-while, factorial

I would like to find the smallest factorial of a given long number. For example, if you enter the number 100, the code should give the factorial 5, since 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120 is closer than the factorial 4! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24. I have written the code below, but when I enter 100, I only get the factorial 3.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long number = scanner.nextLong();
        long factorial = 1;
        long sum;
        do {
            sum = number / factorial;
            factorial++;
        } while (number <= sum);
        System.out.println(factorial);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are talking about "smallest" and "closest". Which one is it? Can you provide more examples so we can see what you are talking about?

Comment: Why is `sum` called sum? You do not sum anything. You should add a print statement to print intermediate results. That will put you into the right direction. Not the cause but helpful to Google: integer division.

Comment: @Progman yes in my task the "smallest" and "closest" means pratically the same. Here I have an excerpt of my task: 

"A user inputs a long positive number m. You need to find out what is the smallest int number n such that n! > m.

n!, or factorial n, is a product of all natural numbers from 1 to n inclusive: for example, 5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5.

For example, the user enters 100. This means m = 100 and n = 5 because 5! = 120 (see the factorial formula) and this is the smallest number that satisfies the condition n! > m."

Comment: @RicardoFerreira Then "closest" is the wrong word here, because it has a different meaning than "smallest". For the input number `130` the "closest" factorial value would be `5! = 120` (difference is `10`), even though the correct answer would be `!6 = 720` (difference is `590`), which is "further" away, but still meets the condition `n! > m`. Please [edit] your question to rephrase your question without using the word "closest". Also add the original assignment text to avoid any confusions.

Answer (score 2):

you should calculate the factorial of numbers, untill you find an equal or smaller number than the number you entered, as shown in the following code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public Long factorial (int n){
      long p = 1L;
      for(int i = 1; i<= n ; i++){
        p=p*i;
      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long number = scanner.nextLong();
        long i = 1;
       while (factorial(i) < number) {
           i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.  This will return the smallest factorial greater than the number.  A record is used to return the information.

```
record Factorial(long n, long nFact) {}
Integer[] data = {1,2,5,10,200,500,2520,1000, 5040, 720, 2000, 3000, 10_000};
for (long i  : data) {
     Factorial result = smallestFactorial(i);
     System.out.printf("For %-8d the smallest >= %8d is (%d! = %d)%n",
             i, i, result.n, result.nFact);
}
```

prints

```
For 1        the smallest >=        1 is (2! = 2)
For 2        the smallest >=        2 is (2! = 2)
For 5        the smallest >=        5 is (3! = 6)
For 10       the smallest >=       10 is (4! = 24)
For 200      the smallest >=      200 is (6! = 720)
For 500      the smallest >=      500 is (6! = 720)
For 2520     the smallest >=     2520 is (7! = 5040)
For 1000     the smallest >=     1000 is (7! = 5040)
For 5040     the smallest >=     5040 is (7! = 5040)
For 720      the smallest >=      720 is (6! = 720)
For 2000     the smallest >=     2000 is (7! = 5040)
For 3000     the smallest >=     3000 is (7! = 5040)
For 10000    the smallest >=    10000 is (8! = 40320)
```

This method calculates the factorial while comparing to the passed argument.

- to save time it memoizes the factorials computed
- continue calculating factorials until the factorial exceeds the argument.
- Then return the information in a record.

```
public static Factorial smallestFactorial(long n) {
   if (n <= 1) {
       return new Factorial(2,2);
   }
   long fact = factorials.floorKey(n);
   int k = factorials.get(fact);
   while (n > fact) {
       fact*=++k;
       factorials.putIfAbsent(fact, k);
   }
   return new Factorial(k, fact);  
}
```

The output formatting is incidental and can of course be changed to suit your requirements.